# choosing only specific columns with ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to lean ng-grid and am having trouble with selecting only specific columns from my data to display. Below is my code:

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50, sex: "Male"},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, sex: "Female"},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27, sex: "Male"},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29, sex: "Male"},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34, sex: "Female"}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { data: myData,
                            columnDefs: [{ field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', width: 90},
                                         { field: 'sex', displayName: 'Sex', width: 90}
                            ]};

});
```

Basically, I'd like to be able to display **only** columns "name" and "sex" in myData. Any help here? I've looked for answers to this question on SO and elsewhere online but haven't found anything. Apologies if this is a dupe.

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/G9YMfp?p=preview) the Plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `myData` inside quotes

```
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData', // <<<<<
        columnDefs: 
          [{ field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', width: 90 },
          { field: 'sex', displayName: 'Sex', width: 90 }
        ]};
```